# Convert log data into time series frequency in spark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

> update
>
> Technically, I want to convert log data into time series frequency in spark. I've searched a lot, but didn't find a good way to deal with big data.
>
> I know pd.dataframe can get count for some feature, but my dataset is too big to use a dataframe.
>
> which means I need to deal with each line by MapReduce.
>
> And what I've tried are probably stupid....

I have a RDD, whose lines are lists of tuples, which looks like:

> [(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1),((datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 2, 0, 4, 12), 1),(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1),(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 4, 12),1)]
>
> [(datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1),(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1)]

In each tuple, the first element is a date,
can I write a map function in spark by python to fill the count of of the tuples with the same (month, day, hour) into a 3-d array according to the date (month, day, hour) as (x,y,z) coordinates in the tuple.

here is what I've done:

```
def write_array(input_rdd, array):
    for item in input_rdd:
        requestTime = item[0]
        array[requestTime.month - 1, requestTime.day  -1, requestTime.hour] += 1

array_to_fill = np.zeros([12, 31, 24], dtype=np.int)
filled_array = RDD_to_fill.map(lambda s:write_array(s, array_to_fill)).collect()

with open("output.txt", 'w') as output:
    json.dump(traffic, output)
```

And the error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "traffic_count.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "traffic_count.py", line 58, in main
    traffic = organic_userList.Map(lambda s: write_array(s, traffic_array)) \
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'Map'
```

I thought there must be some way to save the elements in each line of RDD into a exist data structure..... Can someone help me?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have the output data be a list of `((month, day, hour), count)` values, the following should work:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import datetime

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("WriteDates")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

RDD_to_fill = sc.parallelize([(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1),(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 2, 0, 4, 12), 1),(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1),(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 4, 12),1), (datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 1, 0, 4, 12), 1)])

def map_date(tup):
    return ((tup[0].month, tup[0].day, tup[0].hour), tup[1])

date_rdd = RDD_to_fill.map(map_date).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

# create a tuple for every (month, day, hour) and set the value to 0
zeros = []
for month in range(1,13):
    for day in range(1,32):
        for hour in range(24):
            zeros.append(((month, day, hour), 0))

zeros_rdd = sc.parallelize(zeros)

# union the rdd with the date_rdd (dates with non-zero values) with the zeros_rdd (dates with all zero values)
# and then add aggregate them together (via addition) by key (i.e., date tuple)
filled_tups = date_rdd.union(zeros_rdd).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
```

Then, if you want to access the count for any (month, day, hour) period, you can easily do the following:

```
filled_dict = dict(filled_tups)

# get count for Sept 1 at 00:00
print(filled_dict[(9,1,0)]) # prints 2
```

Note this code doesn't properly account for non-existing days such as Feb 30, Feb 31, April 31, June 31...